# Mysql redesign table with many columns

Tags: mysql, data-structures

I have inherited a table (for text internationalization) with many (50+) columns. The structure is

```
text_id | lang_id | text1 | text2 | text3 | …
----------------------------------------------
1       |       1 | valA1 | valA2 | valA3 | …
2       |       2 | valB1 | valB2 | valB3 | …
```

This is undesirable as not all texts are needed in all languages and mutations, texts are added and I don't feel it to be OK to add columns regularly.

I would like to reformat data to a simple structure:

```
new_text_id | lang_id | name  | value
-------------------------------------
          1 |       1 | text1 | valA1
          2 |       1 | text2 | valA2
…
         61 |       2 | text1 | valB1
         62 |       2 | text2 | valB2
…
```

and so on.

The old `text_id` can be lost, it is not being used at all.

There must be a smarter way of doing this than 50+ times repeating an `INSERT … SELECT` statement, most probably using a `SHOW COLUMNS` query, but I cannot find the correct syntax.

This would get me all column names (in real they are not named `text1` but e.g. `mail_hint`, `mail_cancelled` etc.)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE 
        TABLE_NAME = 'texts' AND 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND 
        COLUMN_NAME <> 'text_id' AND
        COLUMN_NAME <> 'lang_id';
```

And this would import one column into the new structure

```
INSERT INTO texts2 (lang_id, name, value) 
    ( SELECT lang_id, 'text1' AS name, text1 AS value FROM texty ) ;
```

But I am incapable of joining those two.

Comment: Are you trying to get the existing data from old table to new table?

Comment: Exactly. The old structure has one row for the entire language, I want to have one row for each single text (they are ususally short labels).

Comment: You need to write dynamic SQL that generates all the `INSERT ... SELECT` queries from `information_schema` into a string, then uses `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` to execute it. If this is a one-time conversion, this seems like more work than it's worth. Just use something like `awk` to produce all the queries.

Comment: Agree with @Barmar. Better split up the data using awk/perl, process it and get it into new table. How big is the data?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting using awk or perl to process the data, just to create 50 `INSERT` queries that follow the same pattern.

Comment: You are right, this was really simpler - selected column names, rexeped them into array declaration, perl to SQL syntax, executed. Thank you both @Barmar and blackpen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple script to create all the repetitive queries. Here's a `bash` script:

```
for i in {1..50}; do
    echo "INSERT INTO texts2 (lang_id, name, value) 
        ( SELECT lang_id, 'text$i' AS name, text$i AS value FROM texty ) ;"
done | mysql -u username -ppassword dbname
```